# Good books on "advanced" stochastic analysis

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Any good books suggestion for studding advanced features of stochastic analysis ?

Thank's in advance

Comment: What in specific are you looking for?  It's a very, very big field.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian: I'm really searching for any advice in order to have a big list of references to check out.

Comment: "Limit theorems for stochastic processes" and "Markov processes: characterization and convergence" is enough to start reading.

Comment: "Semimartingale theory and stochastic calculus" by He, Wang & Yan, "Diffusions, Markov processes and Martingales" by Rogers & Williams, "Stochastic integration and differential equations" by Protter.